# Why are rotation matrices given in one dimension higher

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Hello Stackexchange :) I am currently reviewing some notes from my linear algebra class and found out that my professor gave the rotation matrices for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an 3x3 matrix and the one for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an 4x4 one. Why is this neccessary? The last column and line of those seems superfluous.

Thank you in advance for your answers! :)

Edit: Here is an example for the rotation by the x-Axis
[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual notes please?

Comment: If you can’t post photos because you’re new, then post a link to them if you’re desperate (although you should learn to use MathJax).

Comment: Adding a dimension lets us reflect with rotations, but I can't guarantee that's the intended point.

Comment: ok I added an example :) This might be it. J.G does this allow us to reflect with rotations even over lines which are not going through the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on.  An *isometry* of $\mathbf R^n$ is a mapping $f: \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^n$ that preserves distances.  If you want $f$ to fix the origin, then $f$ can be described by an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix: $f(\mathbf v) = A\mathbf v$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that $AA^\top = I_n$ (that condition is what captures the "preserving distances" property).

But if you do *not* want to fix the origin, to truly get *all* isometries of $\mathbf R^n$, then you have to allow translations as well. The general isometries of $\mathbf R^n$ have the form
$$
f(\mathbf v) = A\mathbf v + \mathbf b
$$
for an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix and a vector $\mathbf b$ in $\mathbf R^n$.  Note $f(\mathbf 0) = \mathbf b$, so $\mathbf b$ is nothing other than where the origin is sent.  A general isometry of $\mathbf R^n$ can be described as a rotation around the origin followed by a translation in some direction.

Let's call that isometry above $f_{A,\mathbf b}$.  How do two isometries $f_{A,\mathbf b}$ and $f_{A',\mathbf b'}$ compose?  For $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbf R^n$,
$$
(f_{A,\mathbf b} \circ f_{A',\mathbf b'})(\mathbf v) = f_{A,\mathbf b}(A\mathbf v' + \mathbf b) = A(A'\mathbf v + \mathbf b) + \mathbf b' = (AA')\mathbf v + A\mathbf b + \mathbf b'.
$$

So we have the composition rule
$$
f_{A,\mathbf b} \circ f_{A',\mathbf b'} = f_{AA', A\mathbf b + \mathbf b'}.
$$
It turns out that this composition rule can be described by going up $1$ dimension by thinking of $f_{\mathbf A,\mathbf b}$ as the block matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A&\mathbf b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
acting on vectors $\binom{\mathbf v}{1}$ where $\mathbf v \in \mathbf R^n$.
That is, the effect of that $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix on the vector $\binom{\mathbf v}{1}$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A&\mathbf b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}A\mathbf v + \mathbf b\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

It is not important for $A$ to be orthogonal for this "increase dimension by $1$" algebra to work out. For example, take $n = 1$: the function $f(x) = ax + b$ on $\mathbf R$ could be described as an effect of certain $2 \times 2$ matrices on vectors with bottom component $1$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a& b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}ax+b\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

This explains why in the notes you displayed, the vectors on both sides have bottom component $1$ and the orthogonal matrix is in the upper $3 \times 3$ block of the $4 \times 4$ matrix.  The convenience of such notation is it allows the not-entirely-matrix-looking operation $f(\mathbf v) = A\mathbf v + \mathbf b$ with *nonzero* $\mathbf b$ to be described entirely by a matrix operation up one dimension higher using $(\begin{smallmatrix}A&\mathbf b\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$.  If the translation part $\mathbf b$ is $\mathbf 0$, meaning the isometry is a rotation around the origin, then the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix will have zeros along the right column except in the bottom right entry, which will be $1$. And if you *only* want to discuss rotations around the origin, then it is kind of silly (or superfluous, as you wrote) to use the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrices.

A compelling reason to use the larger matrices is the *potential* to allow translations as part of the transformations under consideration.

Another compelling reason is if you want to allow rotations around a *general* point of $\mathbf R^n$, not just the origin.  For example, suppose an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $A$ describes a rotation around $\mathbf 0$ that you are interested in, but you'd like to apply it to rotate around some other point $\mathbf r$ instead.  The way to do this is

1. Translate a vector backwards by $\mathbf r$ ("recenter from $\mathbf r$ to origin")
2. Apply $A$ (desired kind of rotation around origin)
3. Translate forwards by $\mathbf r$ ("recenter from origin to $\mathbf r$).

That means
$$
f(\mathbf v) = A(\mathbf v - \mathbf r) + \mathbf r = 
A\mathbf v + (\mathbf r - A\mathbf r).
$$
Notice $f(\mathbf r) = \mathbf r$, so this is fixing $\mathbf r$ just as you want (a rotation around $\mathbf r$ should not move $\mathbf r$).  This has the form $f(\mathbf v) = A\mathbf v + \mathbf b$ where $\mathbf b = (I_n - A)\mathbf r$.  The upshot is that rotation around a point other than the origin is the same thing as rotation around the origin followed by a certain translation that involves the rotation matrix $A$ and the point $\mathbf r$ you want to be centering everything around.  So even if you are interested *only* in rotations, including rotations around general points of $\mathbf R^n$, you should be allowing translations too and that's where the nonzero $\mathbf b$'s come from merely from interest in rotations (around general points, not just the origin).

Comment: wow ty! This really helped and actually cleared up a question I had about non-origin-centered coordinate systems as well <3 Have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

While It's difficult to say without context, it seems that the notes are referring to [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), a system in which points in $n$-dimensional (projective) space are represented by $n+1$ coordinates, where two coordinate tuples $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are considered equivalent if $\vec{x}=c\vec{y}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. It's common to normalize the last coordinate to $1$ to recover the Euclidean coordinates.

Despite the apparent redundancy, this system has a few advantages, one being that translations can be encoded as matrices just like rotations. As a result, they are used extensively in computer graphics.

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the context I was searching for!